# Why does std::span lack size_type?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-span

I've been updating old code that used my homebrew span class to the one that is more in line with C++20 `std::span` and I'm getting compile errors because `std::span` doesn't have `size_type` and instead has `index_type`. There's been a huge drama over whether `index_type` should be signed or not, but why skipping `size_type`? This breaks generic code that expects containers (or container-like objects) to have `size_type`.

Comment: The [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0122r7.pdf) added `difference_type` for this purpose in R2, so I suspect a proposal to add `size_type` would have a fair shot for C++20.

Comment: That's probably the best answer chris

Comment: What do you need `X::size_type` for?

Comment: @Barry when wrapping containers you usually expose their types.

Comment: @Lyberta ... for what though? If you're just exposing a type for the sake of exposing a type, you could just... not expose the type.

Comment: @Barry And break code down the line that expects usual container with size_type?

Comment: @Lyberta ... which does _what_? I'm just trying ask what is it that you actually use `X::size_type` for - I don't think I've ever seen such code before, so I'm trying to understand the motivation for the question.

Comment: @Lyberta: "*when wrapping containers you usually expose their types.*" `span` is very much *not a container*. Code that expects container-like behavior is likely to fail in ways not detectable by the compiler. The presence or absence of `size_type` will be irrelevant next to those bugs.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ok, then why `std::string_view` has `size_type` then?

Comment: @Lyberta: You misunderstand. Your argument was that `span` needs `size_type` in order to prevent "breaking code down the line that expects usual container with size_type". But code expecting a *container* may already be broken. My point is not that this is the reason why it doesn't have `size_type`; it's that your reason why it *needs* `size_type` doesn't work.

Comment: `string_view` has `size_type` because `string` does; the design intent of `string_view` is to be a drop-in replacement for function parameters of type `string const&`. It is *not* the intent of `span` to be a drop-in replacement for parameters of type `vector const&`.

Comment: @Casey 1) That should be the answer, and 2) thank you for being polite.

Comment: @JonHarper My comment isn't an answer to the original question, it's a response to "why `std::string_view` has `size_type` then?" I honestly have no idea why `span` doesn't have a `size_type` - it certainly has every other nested typedef-name imaginable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything Nevin said ...and it was fixed in [Belfast](https://wg21.link/p1872r0).

Comment: Specifically, [P1872R0](http://wg21.link/p1872R0) was approved.

Answer (score 5):

The original proposal [P1022R0](http://wg21.link/P0122R0), back when it was called `array_view`, had a `size_type` member.  It was removed in the first revision [P1022R1](http://wg21.link/P0122R1) as part of the simplification, as it wasn't needed because `size()` and element access were, at that time, using the signed `index_type` (aka `ptrdiff_t`).  At the Kona 2019 meeting, that decision was changed in [P1227R2](http://wg21.link/P1227R2) by changing `index_type` to be `size_t`.

Comment: They did change it to `size_t`? Yay! I am firmly on the side that sizes should never be signed.